# Convergance of some series of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

Random variables $(X_{n})$ are independent and have the distribution $P(X_{n}=1)=p, P(X_n=-1)=1-p$, $\frac{1}{2}<p<1$. Prove that 
$$X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n \to \infty $$ almost sure.

Let $Y_n^{(a)}:=\begin{cases} X_n if \left|X_n \right| \le a\\ 0 otherwise \end{cases}$.

So this series don't satisfy the necessary contidion from Kolmogorov's three-series theorem (because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\text{E}Y_{n}^{(1)}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2p-1)= \infty$, it must be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}= \infty$.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Hint: Surely you know the behaviour when $n\to\infty$ of the sequence $$\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}n.$$

Comment: It converges to 2p-1>0

Comment: So $X_{1}+\dots+X_{n} \ge (2p-1)n$ almost sure

Comment: And having $2p-1 > 0$ we can conclude that $X_1+\dots+X_n \to \infty$

Comment: @sebuss007 Why not write it as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

Because $(X_n)$ are iid and $\text{E}\left|X_n \right|=1$ from SLLN we have:

$$\overline{X_n} \to \text{E}X_n=2p-1$$

Let $0<q< 2p-1$. So there almost sure is:

$$X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n > qn$$

And having $q>0$ we can conclude that $X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n \to \infty$ a.s.

Comment: No, $S_n/n\to2p-1$ does not imply that $S_n\geqslant(2p-1)n$ for every $n$ large enough. Forget the randomness, how would you proceed to show that a deterministic sequence $(s_n)$ such that $s_n/n\to\ell$ with $\ell>0$, converges to $+\infty$?

Comment: But doesn't it also imply that $S_n \ge (2p-1)n$ almost sure?

Comment: Did you read my previous comment? Anyway, imagine $s_n=(2p-1)n-42$ for every $n$. Then what?

Comment: Oh, I see, you're right, but if we choose some number between 0 and 2p-1, everything will be ok, won't it?

Comment: Because if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n>a$, then $a_n > a$ for every $n$ large enough.

Comment: This is true. $ $

Comment: Thanks, you're very alert :D